# Custom UI for running Activiti Based BPMN work flows

Tags: workflow, activiti, bpmn

One of the main driving factors to use a modern work flow engine like Activiti is it’s support for cloud and multiple tenancy. Our current in house work flow engine lacks these features. So, we are planning to replace it with Activiti.

The current thought process is that we would run Activiti as a standalone (independent) application. Our Application (multiple instances) would interact with the Activiti App using the REST APIs.

Since our current work flow engine is embedded, so is its UI. This means that the work flow pages like user forms etc are rendered as part of our application. We want the UI to remain same so that the transitions for the end users is transparent. So, we cannot reuse the Activiti Explorer, let’s say be rendering Explorer pages within our UI or redirecting to Explorer UI.

This means that we would need to create a UI for Activiti within our web application. Our web application is Struts and Applet based. We are open to use HTML5 but not Spring. My thoughts are that we would need to develop a generic UI framework that would render the BPMN user forms. Are there any Struts/Applet based framework available for this. Behind the scene, an Java API would need to be developed that interact with Activiti Engine using the REST APIs.

Any thoughts/references about how I can go about developing the UI.

Answer (score 1):

Even I am looking for custom UI for Activiti. Little googling has given me the below (apart from Vaadin), but did not found much help around using it for Activiti

http://www.jorambarrez.be/blog/2013/09/03/brazos-for-activiti/

https://github.com/minikomi/Bootstrap-Form-Builder

Also it seems the out-of-the-box activiti explorer UI is hard-wired and not customizable - http://forums.activiti.org/content/ui-customization. Does it mean...no one is using Activiti explorer in production?

Guidance from someone who has someone has gone through this cycle and used custom UI will be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be XForms. For example, Orbeon (http://www.orbeon.com/) is a java-based XForms Engine which can be used as stand-alone server. In addition, orbeon offers a servlet filter to integrate the XForms-Rendering in your own application.

We realized an XForms-Integration with Activiti and it works very well. Hope this helps.